# What is the correct way of exporting Hooks function as a component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to Hooks and would like to understand better how to do things the right way. I am trying to separate my component into a Home and SignIn. Simple example:

Home.js

```
 import {SignIn} from './SignIn';

 export const Home = () => {
    return (
       <div>
          <SignIn />
       </div>
    )
 }
```

SignIn.js

```
 export const SignIn = () => {
   //sign in functionality
  return (
     //sign in forms
   )
  }
```

with this format it works but on the console I'm having error:

```
  Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of 
  <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
  
  in SignIn (at Home.js:26)
```

What would be the correct way of exporting Hooks to be a valid react child?

Comment: I do not see hooks in your code as of this writing. I recommend you read the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html).

Comment: The error is in SignIn, which has no code shown.

Comment: Yes the error is in the SignIn which I imported inside Home as a component not as a function

Comment: My point is that if the error is in a component, and you don’t include enough source to demonstrate the issue, nobody can help in a meaningful way.

Comment: I got it working now by Liu Lei's example below. Because I have this {method} inside return which I put outside the form though it is inside the container div it is causing the error, so I just wrap it in it's own div like in the example and the error is now gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u do that. u'll got this "Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it."

```
const method = () => {}

...
return (
    <div>
      {method}
    </div>
  );
```

changed

```
const method = () => {}

...
return (
    <div>
      {method()}
    </div>
  );
```

in your SignIn.js

```
export const SignIn = () => {
  return (
   // the problem is here
   // do like that {method()}
  );
};
```

============UPDATE==============

SignIn.js

```
import React from 'react'

export const SignIn = () => {
  return <div>SignIn</div>
}
```

Home.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {SignIn} from './SignIn';

export const Home = () => {
    return (
       <div>
          <SignIn />
       </div>
    )
 }
```

Comment: given that I already have it. I did not include it in the example.

Comment: if u return a Function u will get this err.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: If I do this {SignIn()} the error for SignIn is gone but instead the error is "in div (at Home.js:25)" something like this

Comment: I mean u should checked the file of SignIn.js

Comment: You are right, I have a conditional statement inside return() that is causing the error. thanks I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make React recognize that it is a component by doing so
In your SignIn.js and your Home.js:

```
import React from "react";
```

Updated, try this:

```
export const SignIn = () => {
  return <div>SignIN</div>;
};

export const Home = () => {
  return <SignIn />;
};
```

Comment: i did not include this in the example given that i already have it.

Comment: sorry I miss type that home part but I already have it as well, I corrected the example

Comment: hmmmmmm, you...........I.......speechless.......I updated my answer again

Comment: I tried your sample without () and <div> but the error is still there, the error only appears on the console